# FFI in PLT Racket with openCV

Tags: c, opencv, scheme, racket, ffi

I'd like to control my webcam through PLT Racket, and ideally to make a light wrapper library for some of OpenCV's C api. I'm having a little trouble, though, in that I'm not sure which object files from OpenCV are the libraries... embarrassing, I know. I looked at how the Python API is working, and I see that the modules there are in the cv.so file, but I'm not sure what to use in my binaries. I'm on Mac OSX

I have this

```
(get-ffi-obj function-name (ffi-lib lib-name) format)...)
```

but I'm not sure which file to pass as "lib-name". 
In my installation directory for opencv I have ../opencv/2.2/lib which contains a number of .dylib files. None seem to work, but they are the best guess so far. Do I need to build OpenCV with different compiler options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on OSX `.dylib` files are these (dynamic) libraries.  On windows they would be `.dll` files and on linux `.so`.  Note that `ffi-lib` does some searching so you can use a single name and it will use the system's facility (eg, `dlopen()`) to look for a library.

Comment: thanks, Eli. So it looks like the library files were compiled in some way that is incompatible with my Racket installation? I ran: (ffi-lib "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2/lib/libopencv_core"), and the result was (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2/lib/libopencv_core.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2/lib/libopencv_core.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture).

Comment: Possibly -- you're now going off to OSX-specific problems, and I have nearly zero experience with that.

Comment: @Ben: This is just a hunch, but it sounds like a 32-bit/64-bit mismatch (the lib is there, but the architecture is wrong). I believe Racket is 32-bit, and since you installed OpenCV with Homebrew, you probably have a 64-bit build of that. I'm afraid I have no idea how to make brew build 32-bit binaries.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Thanks for the guess- I think you're probably right about that. I'll probably have to slow down and see if I can rebuild OpenCV the hard way. Either that or move development over to the old 32 bit machine.